# window.this is undefined while window.window gives window object

Tags: javascript, window, this

In the following code, why does window.this return "undefined" while window.window return window object ?

```
let x = this.window;
let y = window.window;
let z = window.this;

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

Comment: Because `window` has a `window` property but not a `this` property?

Comment: Let me answer your question with another question. In the global scope, what is `this`?

Comment: For your reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#instance_properties

Comment: `this` is a keyword. `window.this` looks up an arbitrary property called `this` on `window`; it doesn’t exist in a Web environment by default.